# Neural networks - function approximation

Tags: approximation, neural-networks

I am facing the following problem:
Given a list a list of measurements like this [random measurements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruoVx.png) I want to construct an ANN to make up the function. After that I need to be able for a new measurement to get the value of the approximation function. What are the steps I should follow? To my understanding first I need to train the network but how can I achieve that if I don't have any value for output? Second thing how will be I able to reuse the function approximation for a new measurement so it lies on the function approximation curve?

I will use the [FANN](http://leenissen.dk/) library.

Comment: You DO have a value for the output. That value is the measured value, your input should be the index.

Comment: @ThomasW if I have a measurement let's say 200, 350, 700 lux what is my input? After I will train the network, I assume I will have a function approximation. So given a new value reading let's say 280 lux how can I be able to detect how much that value is divergent to the value of approximation function?

Comment: It seems to me that you need to learn some basics first. You could read chapter 4.3 and 4.4 of [my bachelors thesis](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.09030)

Comment: @MartinThoma I have read it but still I don't get how can I obtain the trained system to predict values according to the approximation function.